# Load multiple .csv files in R, edit them and save as new .csv files named by a list of chracter strings

Tags: r, csv, lapply

I am pretty new to R and programming so I do apologies if this question has been asked elsewhere.

I'm trying to load multiple .csv files, edit them and save again. But cannot find out how to manage more than one .csv file and also name new files based on a list of character strings.

So I have .csv file and can do:

```
species_name<-'ace_neg'

{species<-read.csv('species_data/ace_neg.csv')

species_1_2<-species[,1:2]

species_1_2$species<-species_name

species_3_2_1<-species_1_2[,c(3,1,2)]

write.csv(species_3_2_1, file='ace_neg.csv',row.names=FALSE)}
```

But I would like to run this code for all .csv files in the folder and add text to a new column based on .csv file name.

So I can load all .csv files and make a list of character strings for use as a new column text and as new file names.

```
NDOP_files <- list.files(path="species_data", pattern="*.csv$", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)

short_names<- substr(NDOP_files, 14,20)
```

Then I tried:

```
lapply(NDOP_files, function(x){
  species<-read.csv(x)
  species_1_2<-species[,1:2]
  species_1_2$species<-'name' #don't know  how to insert first character string of short_names instead of 'name', than second character string from short_names for second csv. file etc.
```

Then continue in the code to change an order of columns

```
species_3_2_1<-species_1_2[,c(3,1,2)]
```

And then write all new modified csv. files and name them again by the list of short_names.

I'm sorry if the text is somewhat confusing.

Any help or suggestions would be great.

Comment: Hi, to help yourself, and others, dput (r function) some data and then four or five file names found down the species_data path. I understand you want to automate this, but help us understand a little better what the 'this' is with a little data so we can play with it on our machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually quite close and using `lapply()` is really good idea.
As you state, the issue is, it only takes one `list` as an argument,
but you want to work with two. `mapply()` is a function in `base R` that you can feed multiple lists into and cycle through synchronically. `lapply()` and `mapply()`are both designed to create/ manipulate objects in`R`but you want to write the files and are not interested in the out within`R`. The`purrr`package has the`walk*()\` functions which are useful,
when you want to cycle through lists and are only interested in creating
side effects (in your case saving files).

`purrr::walk2()` takes two lists, so you can provide the data and the
file names at the same time.

```r
library(purrr)
```

First I create some example data (I’m basically already using the same concept here as I will below):

```r
test_data <- map(1:5, ~ data.frame(
  a = sample(1:5, 3),
  b = sample(1:5, 3),
  c = sample(1:5, 3)
))
walk2(test_data,
      paste0("species_data/", 1:5, "test.csv"),
      ~ write.csv(.x, .y))
```

Instead of getting the file paths and then stripping away the path
to get the file names, I just call `list.files()`, once with `full.names = TRUE` and once with `full.names = FALSE`.

```r
NDOP_filepaths <-
  list.files(
    path = "species_data",
    pattern = "*.csv$",
    full.names = TRUE,
    recursive = FALSE
  )

NDOP_filenames <-
  list.files(
    path = "species_data",
    pattern = "*.csv$",
    full.names = FALSE,
    recursive = FALSE
  )
```

Now I feed the two lists into `purrr::walk2()`. Using the `~` before
the curly brackets I can define the anonymous function a bit more elegant
and then use `.x`, and `.y` to refer to the entries of the first and the
second list.

```r
walk2(NDOP_filepaths, 
      NDOP_filenames,
      ~ {
        species <- read.csv(.x)
        species <- species[, 1:2]
        species$species <- gsub(".csv", "", .y)
        write.csv(species, .x)
      })
```

Learn more about `purrr` at [purrr.tidyverse.org](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/).

Alternatively, you could just extract the file name in the loop and stick to `lapply()` or use `purrr::map()`/`purrr::walk()`, like this:

```r
lapply(NDOP_filepaths, 
      function(x) {
        species <- read.csv(x)
        species <- species[, 1:2]
        species$species <- gsub("species///|.csv", "", x)
        write.csv(species, gsub("species///", "", x))
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NDOP_files <- list.files(path="species_data", pattern="*.csv$", 
full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)

# Get name of each file (without the extension)

# basename() removes all of the path up to and including the last path seperator
# file_path_sands_ext() removes the .csv extension

csvFileNames <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(NDOP_files))
```

Then, I would write a function that takes in 1 csv file and does some manipulation to the file and outputs out a data frame. Since you have a list of csv files from using `list.files`, you can use the `map` function in the purrr package to apply your function to each csv file.

```
doSomething <- function(NDOP_file){
# your code here to manipulate NDOP_file to your liking
return(NDOP_file)

NDOP_files <- map(NDOP_files, ~doSomething(.x))
```

Lastly, you can manipulate the file names when you write the new csv files using `csvFileNames` and a custom function you write to change the file name to your liking. Essentially, use the same architecture of defining your custom function and using map to apply to each of your files.